# Why doesn't this HAProxy ACL match the HTTP method from returned from a map?

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to configure HAProxy to allow a specific set of HTTP methods to a specific set of paths, stored in a map.

For example, I have a haproxy map file which contains the following:

```
/api/read_method GET
/api/write_method POST
```

Given the above map, I would like to allow `GET` requests starting with `/api/read_method` (but no other methods), and `POST` requests to paths starting `/api/write_method` (but no GETs).

Based on the documentation, I have arrived at the following haproxy configuration:

```
listen main
    # bind, doesn't really matter
    bind *:443 ssl crt server.pem
    # use path_beg to find the map entry starting with the path
    # compare the request method with the returned map entry, case insensitively as astring
    acl map_method method -i -m str %[path,map_beg(acl.map)]
    
    http-request deny unless map_method
    server app backend:80
```

This ACL never seems to match, the request is always denied, even when I test as follows:

```
curl -v https://localhost/api/read_method # do a GET to the path in the map
```

I have attempted to debug this using the following line, as a modification to the `http-request deny` statement:

```
http-request return status 401 content-type text/plain lf-string "Denied, allowed method for %[path] is >(%[path,map_beg(acl.map)])< but method was >(%[method])<" unless url_method
```

This denies the request with a log-format message, which returns as follows:

```
Denied, allowed method for /api/read_method is >(GET)< but request method is >(GET)<
```

I don't understand why this condition isn't satisfying the ACL, the strings are identical and the comparison is done as a string (`-m str`). The map is definitely returning the appropriate method (shown in the debug string), and if I swap the map lookup for a literal "`GET`", the ACL passes correctly (but not when the same string is returned from the lookup).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't match because `%[path,map_beg(acl.map)]` doesn't expand. It is literally those characters, starting with a percent sign, that the ACL is comparing your `method` to. For proof, you can [see my stackoverflow question where I try this with IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77226556/haproxy-acl-with-dynamic-pattern).

If you replace it with a hardcoded `GET`, you'll see that your `read_method` starts working.

As for how to get an ACL to work with a dynamic pattern, [I would also like to know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77226556/haproxy-acl-with-dynamic-pattern).